# Unable to create a new discussion in Area 51 Proposal Page

Tags: bug, area-51

I have just committed to a proposal on Area 51: [Gamification](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44478/gamification?referrer=59P3Q-atUQqFjW89D8Xglg2)

I wish to add a new discussion but I am not able to do so and redirected to the Login page repeatedly, in-spite of being already logged in.

I have logged in multiple times, use Windows 8 Professional and latest version of Google Crome.

What's wrong? What should I do?

This is clearly a bug in the system. It's so serious that I now have two accounts on Area51 with exactly the same credentials and details.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hrm. Have you tried a different browser? Do you see any errors in Chrome dev tools?

Comment: Naughty. Trying to game the gamification proposal eh? Tsk tsk tsk...

Comment: @Mat I don't understand as to what are you saying, but I am not upto anything.

Comment: @Mat was just making a joke, about you gaming the gamification proposal. (See the play on words. `:))`)

Comment: The link to the proposal you give is linked to this user account: http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/93015/user221287. In fact, I just committed, and that account got a higher total reputation. (That is, in the case you wonder why there is much difference, now.)

Comment: @kiamlaluno Dude, let that be. Anyhow, this problem is real, this image that I have shown is real and so the bug is real. We should concentrate on the bug here. Forget the link.

Comment: I was just pointing out which one was the correct account; nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Odd. Both the A51 accounts link back to the same network account.